# Will android root detection techniques work the same for rooted Oculus devices?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, jailbreak, oculus, rooted-device

I am building an Oculus Quest/ Quest2 application via Unity. While android, there are mixed hushed opinions on the web regarding how Oculus has been rooted. I am unable to determine if general android root detection methods work for Oculus Quest devices.

I am presently using the approach here, with some device info changes:
https://github.com/lhamed/Unity-Android-Root-Build-Status-Checker/blob/master/ApkValidater.cs

From what I understand, the device user can give or take away root access from any application, therefore will my application, if denied, still be able to detect if the device has been rooted or not?

Also, apart from Oculus devices, I understand that any normal Android device can be rooted, unlocked OEM, then install other custom ROMs to support apps that are bound to those Operating systems. Once again I found people claiming they have done this with Oculus 2, but nothing concrete.
I dont think such a device would support the same, but even if applications are atleast executed on such a system, would that provide a basis on which mods can be built and tested?

Please guide.